# On Perl's List::Util's "shuffle" method. How to "unshuffle"?

Tags: perl, shuffle

I tend to use shuffle method to randomize the order of elements of a list. For example, here's a code that messes up roles for a little game:

```
 sub assign_roles {
       my ( $role_num_map ) = @_;
       my @roles;
       for my $role ( keys %$role_num_map ) {
         next if $role_num_map->{$role} == 0;
         push @roles, $role for ( 1 .. $role_num_map->{$role} );
       }
       my @shuffled_roles = shuffle @roles;
 }
```

My question is, how does "shuffle" randomizes the order? What method does it use? 
**How can I go back from @shuffled_roles to $role_num_map ?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`shuffle` randomizes the order. Thus, this operation cannot be reverted (much like you can't uncook a fried egg by putting it into the fridge). But we can use a trick: Shuffling indices instead of values:

```
my @items = 'a' .. 'z';  # things we want to shuffle
my @shuffled_idxs = shuffle 0 .. $#items;
my @shuffled = @items[@shuffled_idxs]; # using a slice to do the actual shuffling
```

From the `@shuffled_idxs`, we can make an array that allows reverse lookup:

```
my @reverse_idxs;
$reverse_idxs[$shuffled_idxs[$_]] = $_ for 0 .. $#shuffled_idxs;

# now we can use a slice to reverse the shuffling:
my @reversed = @shuffled[@reverse_idxs];
```

When we print out `@items`, `@shuffled`, and `@reversed`, we could get the following output:

```
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
hyaxruvnogekdzjmbpilstcqfw
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

This works fine for arrays. Your example is a bit different, because you have sequences like

```
a b b b c c
```

and you want to make the hash `{ a => 1, b => 3, c => 2 }`. This can be done without unshuffling, using normal counting instead:

```
my %reversed;
$reversed{$_}++ for @shuffled_roles;
```

However, you skip over roles which map to zero. As this information is no longer present in the role array, it cannot be recreated.

Comment: I'm struggling to extend index-shuffle to the fried egg analogy :)

Comment: proteine destruction via heating is the classical example for one-way operations in biology. During heating, the bonds that sustain the spatial structure of the proteine break up and realign randomly. The information about the original structure is lost in that process, and the properties of the proteine changed visibly (in the case of eggs: colour and consitency change from glibbery-transparent to solid-white)

Comment: Your explanation is for shuffling the actual list (scrambled egg in culinary terms), but the index-shuffle trick you show essentially allows you see what the egg looks like when scrambled without actually cooking the egg. What I was saying was that it would be cool to see the egg analogy extended to represent the index-shuffle example :)